# Laravel showing plain 500 error (no Whoops or Ignition)

Tags: php, laravel

**Solved**

I had a folder called `.ignition` in my home directory. Removing the folder solved the problem.

**Update**

Upon further inspection of the logs, I'm getting the following error:

`[2020-08-19 16:56:45] local.ERROR: Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider::Facade\Ignition\{closure}(): Failed opening required '/Users/username/.ignition'  (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.16/share/php@7.3/pear') {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError(code: 0):  Facade\\Ignition\\IgnitionServiceProvider::Facade\\Ignition\\{closure}(): Failed opening required '/Users/username/.ignition' (include_path=' .:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7 .3/7.3.16/share/php@7.3/pear') at /Users/username/PhpstormProjects/test/vendor/facade/ignition/src/IgnitionServiceProvider.php:202)`

**Orignal**

When throwing a custom exception from a controller (`throw new Exception('Test Exception');`) I'm getting a plain 500 error rather than the Ignition (or Whoops) debug pages in my Laravel `7.24` application. I have `APP_DEBUG` set to `true` and `APP_ENV` set to `local`.

Digging a bit deeper it seems as though the following line in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` is checking to see if `Whoops` exists and uses that check to return either the Symfony error page or the Whoops one.

```php
return config('app.debug') && class_exists(Whoops::class)
                        ? $this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($e)
                        : $this->renderExceptionWithSymfony($e, config('app.debug'));
```

If I run `dd(class_exists(Whoops::class))` I get `true` despite it being absent from my `composer.json` file. What's strange is that it looks like `Ignition` is pulling in `filp/whoops` as one of its dependencies, making this always true. `Ignition` is installed (as per the `composer.json` file below) but the error page is not showing. How does the Ignition package render its page if not from the `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php` file?

To summarise, the logs are showing my exception being thrown but a simple `500` error with no context is being shown in the browser.

Any suggestions where I might look next?

```json
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4.9",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.5",
    "laravel/cashier": "^11.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
    "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
    "laravel/telescope": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.11",
    "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^2.8"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.4",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
  },
  "config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": []
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
      "app/Http/Support/Helpers/action_response_helpers.php"
    ],
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ]
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
      "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The HTTP 500 error page should usually hint at the error.log for more concrete infos. You ventured too far into implementation details. The Whoops page (or whatever) isn't even relevant for more crude setup/config/parser issues.

Comment: To clarify, I’m intentionally throwing the error. The issue here is that I can’t see exceptions in the browser.

Comment: What's the actual error you got? Not all errors will be catched by your application

Comment: The error is being thrown by me using `throw new Exception('Test Exception')`.

Comment: Could you update your question with the stack trace of the error and the line of the code that's outputting this error?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question with a log entry that might be pointing to why the Ignition page isn't showing.

Comment: Glad you came with a solution.